# Jquery validation Error when trying to validate a bootstrap checkbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using Jquery validation plugin, everything work fine but when i try to validate the check box i got an error:

```
TypeError: b is undefined
```

here's my bootstrap checkbox script:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" required> I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and here's the jquery validation that i used:

```
$("#formRegister").validate({
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "help-block",
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                // Only validation controls
                if (!$(element).hasClass('novalidation')) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                // Only validation controls
                if (!$(element).hasClass('novalidation')) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
                else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio' && element.parent('.radio-inline').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
                }
                else if (element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                    error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Might not be a bad idea to search through the SO questions tagged with [tag:jquery-validate]... and thoroughly [read the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/).

Comment: i always search before posting here fyi. let me know if u found the same problem. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I stopped after I found four of the same... see duplicate links up top.  Also, when you read the documentation you'll see [an option called `debug`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug) that would warn you when a field is missing the `name` attribute.

Comment: @Sparky thanks. i will take a look of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A required input also must have a `name`. Without a name it won't be submitted by browser and therefore can't also be required

```
<input name="terms" type="checkbox" required>
```

Comment: it work but why it doesn't have a red color like the other input?

Comment: No idea....... .Create a [mcve] if that's a problem also

Comment: i think i have to modify it in the errors placements. i think i just have to find the right parents for the errors class. thanks,